# Problem with URLRead[] and URLSubmit[] on Linux

Tags: web-access

**Update**

I originally thought there was something wrong with my usage of URLRead. But then I switched from my Mathematica instance on Ubuntu 17.10 to an instance on OS X 10.11 and it works fine on OS X.

So... Is this an issue with my installation? Or a bug in Mathematica on Linux?

In addition to the problem below, another (most likely related) issue is with `URLSubmit`.

```
URLSubmit["http://www.wolfram.com", 
  HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskFinished" -> Print|>]
```

This gives the following error.

```
Failure["URLSubmitFailure", 
  Association[
    "MessageTemplate" :> MessageName[URLSubmit, "invak"],
    "MessageParameters" -> {
      Association["TaskFinished" -> Print]
    }
  ]
]
```

**Original**

I have a rest call that I'm using to talk to an Elasticsearch instance that looks like this with cURL.

```
curl -XGET "http://elastic00.example.com:9200/test-index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "AWDd8gqhdJ9xvhUtDICa"
    }
  }
}'
```

I can use this with no problems if I run it as an external call from Mathematica.

```
RunProcess[{"curl",
   "-XGET", "http://elastic00.example.com:9200/test-index/_search",
   "-H", "Content-Type: application/json",
   "-d", "{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"_id\":\"AWDd8gqhdJ9xvhUtDICa\"}}}" 
  }, "StandardOutput"]
```

But when I use `HTTPRequest` with `URLRead` it doesn't work.

```
req = HTTPRequest[
  URLBuild[<|
    "Scheme" -> "http",
    "Domain" -> "elastic00.example.com",
    "Port" -> 9200,
    "Path" -> {"test-index", "_search"}|>],
  <|
   "ContentType" -> "application/json",
   "Body" -> ExportString[{"query" -> {"match" -> {"_id" -> "AWDd8gqhdJ9xvhUtDICa"}}}, "JSON"]
   |>
  ]

URLRead[req]
```

I get an error saying that it is an `InvalidLocation`

```
Failure["InvalidLocation", 
  Association[
    "MessageTemplate" -> "Specified request is invalid", 
    "MessageParameters" -> Association[]]]
```

Comment: Does the host elastic00.example.com exists at all? Even `ping` can't resolve it.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov No that's just an example url. It's an internal site that unreachable externally anyway so I just used 'example.com'. I was trying to reproduce this with an externally accessible URL but then I found out that it's a Linux specific issue. So I figured it's not that relevant anyway. You can reproduce the issue with the `URLSubmit` example at the top. It's the first example in the the documentation for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was an issue with the system not being fully set up after installation. After a reboot of the OS, it works fine.